# Displace graphics over fabric?

Tags: displacement

Obligatory 'I'm new to blender comment.'

I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction for tutorials, but can't seem to find something relevant.

I want to displace a face onto this object, so it wraps and maps around the surface.

[image]

This was made with a plane and fabric mod draped over a sphere.

I'm not even sure if displacement is the right term, I'm just referring to how I might do it in photoshop.

The end goal is something like this (done in Photoshop): [image]

Comment: Hi :). Should be fairly easy, simply add the texture and move the UV to adjust the position. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @JachymMichal firstly I tried it with shrink wrap approach but because of the angles of fabric it didn't quite work, then I looked at stencil, but I couldn't get that to show in render and adding the base colour was messing around with the texture and translucent fabric I was looking for, UV mapping feels the best approach but it feels like a big area to learn - which doesn't mean I'm not going to - I was just wondering if there was a simpler method for a beginner such as myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add a plane
2. add subdivision modifier

[image]

3. move it up
4. add a sphere, scale it down in edit mode

[image]

5. add a cloth modifier to your plane
6. physics: add collision to your sphere
7. shade smooth your sphere
8. add another subdivision surface to your plane
9. result so far:

[image]

10. go back to frame 1 -> select the plane
11. go to shading tab -> New

[image]

12. press CTRL-T with the principled bsdf selected (note: this needs to have the node wrangler add-on enabled)

[image]

13. on the image texture node open any image you want to show on your plane, choose clipped...

[image]

14. ...and change position and scale and rotation on the mapping node as you need it

[image]

[image]

15. for your "base color/texture/image/whatever" just add a color mix node like this:

[image]

of course you can plug in a texture/other image/whatever you want in color1 value of the mix shader. I was just too lazy ;)

my lazy result: ( i am sure you can do better!! )

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. From a process POV, does this mean it's trial and error until I can position the face in the place I want it? For example, returning to frame one, placing in the face, running animation, if the face it out of place, back to frame one to move face?

Comment: Yes, but it should be pretty easy to do that.

Comment: Final question, if the plane was give a translucent or transparent look - would the graphic become transparent? If so, can that be avoided?

Comment: No it wouldn’t.

Comment: And if you still got problems, provide your blend file and I will help you

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create the cutout shapes as a send object, then use a `Boolean` modifier on the cloth set to Difference.

Alternatively, you could use `UV`(<kbd>U</kbd>)->`Project from View` to get texture coordinates along the view plane, then paint your texture as you have done in photoshop.